# c# class inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible to inherit from a base class, which inherits from another base class?

Comment: Yes that's possible of course.

Comment: And of course you tried it before you posted?

Comment: yes i tried it, but i got an error " Error 8 Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'commercial' is less accessible than class

Comment: You typically see that message when the base class is private - it is therefore "less accessible"

Comment: and you made sure all classes are equally accessible (all public for example)? Do a search for ".net class access modifiers" and be amazed!

Comment: From the error above, it sounds like maybe your base class is not public

Comment: "accessibility" is the modifier before your class declaration. By default a class is "private" if no modifier is put before the class declaration. Try making both your base class and subclass public.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inheritance goes as deeply as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer provided in the question you asked before: [c-abstract-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798280/c-abstract-classes).

I am not going to rewrite that code but if it's not perfect and it's give you errors then you need to do some debugging.  Often times, people write code here that isn't 100% error free.

You need to run that code that was given to you and ask a SPECIFIC question about a SPECIFIC error.  Post what you have tried and what you are trying to do along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is! Look [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson08.aspx). You know, there's a lot of reading you should do. Possibilities are exciting!

If you show us the code you are trying, maybe you would get more help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only inherit from one class, but that class may inherit from another.